# Magento Import Product With image in CSV

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

i am upload a csv file that contain products and its image . when i read the documentation they says that you need to place images in intall_directory/media/import/file_name.jpg

I do the same thing also give right to folder but when i import it says Image does not exist.

```
sku,name,description,price,_store,status,visibility,thumbnail,image,_category,type,_product_websites,short_description,weight,tax_class_id,attribute_set
testnew121_prrrrrrodusssct121hissam bbb,This Is test New Producssst1 hissam,Description of New Product1,18.45,default,1,4,platon_photographer-president-mahmoud-ahmadinejad-portrait_1.jpeg,platon_photographer-president-mahmoud-ahmadinejad-portrait_1.jpeg,Closeouts,simple,base,short_description,5,4,Default
```

Comment: please add your sample CSV.

Comment: updated my question please check it

Comment: Have a look at http://www.integer-net.com/2012/04/04/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/, section "Product Images". Perhaps this will help.

Comment: did you check file permission is `775`? also try with `small_image` field

Answer (score 3):

Please Follow Below steps for import Products :

1. create folder in Root/media/import/ and place all images in import folder.
2. Set permission to 777
3. Add only /imagename.extesnion in csv file not full path
4. then import.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly add the / (slash) before image name.

```
sku,name,description,price,_store,status,visibility,thumbnail,image,_category,type,_product_websites,short_description,weight,tax_class_id,attribute_set
testnew121_prrrrrrodusssct121hissam bbb,This Is test New Producssst1 hissam,Description of New Product1,18.45,default,1,4,/platon_photographer-president-mahmoud-ahmadinejad-portrait_1.jpeg,/platon_photographer-president-mahmoud-ahmadinejad-portrait_1.jpeg,Closeouts,simple,base,short_description,5,4,Default
```